# Object in the flow stuck between PutFile and ExecuteScript for longer time than expected

Tags: apache-nifi

when I am using PutFile Processor and ExecuteScript Processor,the object in the flow between them stuck for longer time than expected and processed many times.
this case happend only between these 2 processors only.

the version of the NIFI I am usnig is: NIFI v1.18, also I tried to upgrade and use version 1.22, but this issue still as is.

The script I am using in ExecuteScript is:

```
``
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.OutputStreamCallback

def flowFile = session.create()

def filePath = 'E:/tmp/tmp_file.txt'
def file = new File(filePath)

if (file.exists()) {
def fileContent = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(file))

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, { outputStream ->
outputStream.write(fileContent)
} as OutputStreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
} else {
session.remove(flowFile)
// Handle file not found or other error
}
``
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjvli.png)

even if I set the expiration time for the flow and set it to 1 second, and scheduled the run of ExecuteScript to 4 sec, still processing the flow at least 2 times.
which cause sending the file to the API many times.

Comment: Any specific reason for not using [FetchFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.23.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchFile/index.html) instead of the ExecuteScript ?

Comment: Cause I want to convert the file to stream of bytes based on the mentioned code to send it through API, I don't know if the fetch file will achieve this goal or not, I did not use it before

Comment: based on Fetchfile description, it is fetching the content of the file and streams it, but in my case I want to send the file (not the content only) as stream of byte array to API.